# Classical to another style guitar

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, acoustic-guitar, rock

I played classical and have done Trinity Grade 4. I dont enjoy listening to classical guitar songs . I enjoy the rock/pop type music. Hence I want to change my style . In which styles will the finger picking / arpeggio playing technique be useful to proceed so that i can build upon my previous knowledge. I only used to play from sheet music. My playing from ear is weak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just about any type of music can be played using finger picking arrangements or arpeggio or individual note picking with a plectrum or a combination.

Country, folk, bluegrass, rock, blues, all can be played in a manner and style that will allow you to utilize the skills you learned playing classical.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a flamenco guitar player, so I naturally suggest you try listening to something played by Paco de Lucia, Tomatito or Sabicas and see if it grabs you by the hottanannys as it did me 40 years ago :-)